# background to panel in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I m having a imagecontrol in asp.net which has only panel,
i have to set the panel's background through code,
i gave the file path of the image which it has to set 
like this,

this.Panel1.BackImageUrl = @"D:\Backup\deepasundari\Asp.net\PhotoSlideShow\PhotoSlideShow\Sample Pictures\15flowers1024.jpg";

but it s not getting set.
Do anyone knows how to set this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the image on your project then reference from it.

In visual studio's solution explorer create a folder named "images" then paste your image in it. Reference the image in that location (i.e "~/images/15flowers1024.jpg"). lets see if it works.